# Smart Target: A/B testing and Multivariate Testing

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper, experience-optimization

we have a requirement to do A/B testing or Multivariate Testing on sites using web 8.1 as CMS and DD4T .net MVC web application.

Is there a way we can write rules in Fredhopper (Smart Target) to achieve A/B content testing? Have anyone already tried this?

Also, found this [link](https://www.convert.com/integrations/sdl-tridion-ab-testing-multivariate-testing/) which talks about my scenario.

Comment: are you looking for the functionality that Experiments provides (this is OOB Smart Target functionality, that allows you to do A/B testing)
http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2/GUID-44802E9F-1619-4A1E-B4FF-E8493152D121

Comment: Hi Harald, thanks for your response. Yes I'm looking for this only. thanks again for highlighting this. Somehow i have missed it.

Comment: i'll move this comment to a response then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do A/B testing using a Smart Target functionality called Experiments. This allows you to define two or more variants of content, which will be shown randomly to visitors (visitor A will see variant A, visitor B will see variant B, etc...)

Using the Experiments gui, you are able to see the number of times each variant is shown, and how many conversions(clicks) you get per variant.

You can find more info on this feature in the documentation : http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2/GUID-44802E9F-1619-4A1E-B4FF-E8493152D121